# Would an O'Neill Colony in earth orbit need to rotate around an axis parallel to the Earth to keep people from feeling major weight changes?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency

I calculated that if an O'Neill cylinder were allowed to rotate around an axis that pointed away from Earth (or anywhere in a plane that is perpendicular to Earth) that the variation in experienced orbital speed as the cylinder rotates, for an individual on the inner surface, would be +/- 173 m/s which translates to +/- .38 m/s^2 as far as gravitational effect. This would be about 15 lbs feel in weight change for a 200 lbs individual during a 2 minute rotation.  Am I right about this issue? Would this be tolerable?

This is based on the idea of a cylinder about 1000 miles off the surface of the Earth, radius 2 miles - which is what I generally see people considering as the parameters for such a structure. (Speed to maintain orbit=19908 m/s, rotation speed at inner surface 173 m/s)

If right, does this mean such a thing only works if far from Earth at L-points? If one were put in low earth orbit, is this weight issue a bigger issue than pointing it towards the sun? or any other preferred orientation consideration?

Comment: I'm not fluent enough in the calculations to attempt to add an answer, but what I do know of the O'Neil Cylinder, is that they won't spin the way you want them to. They want to spin where the moment is greatest. So an egg-shaped object will spin around an the major axis (top to bottom or bottom to top, not sideways, if that makes sense). And complex objects like a T-shape will snap around (do a 180) every few rotations. The Standford torus is the safer bet.

Comment: I believe i understand what you are asking but it is not really clear. The are multiple possible axis of rotation to be talking about.  Perhaps another way of describing it?: O'neil cylinder is in earth orbit wtih the north end pointing towards a fixed point say constellation Aries. Then as it orbits earth, local net 'gravity' will change.

Comment: The orbital velocity you list is  higher than Earth's surface escape velocity. Orbital velocity for a circular orbit at 1600 km  altitude over Earth is about [7000 m/s](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=orbital+velocity+calculator&assumption=%7B%22FS%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%7B%22CircularOrbitSpeed%22%2C+%22vc%22%7D%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22CircularOrbitSpeed%22%2C+%22m%22%7D+-%3E%221+earth+Mass%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22CircularOrbitSpeed%22%2C+%22r%22%7D+-%3E%221+earth+radius+%2B+1000+miles%22).

Comment: Hello Parity. You've not taken our [tour] nor read through our [help] and so don't realize that asking more than one question is a reason to close a question (click the "close" link and read "Needs More Focus"). I generally try not to close new user questions, so could you [edit] your post to ask one and only one question?

Comment: @AlexandraWilliams While that is true, it is also irrelevant. If you were to build a naked rotating cylinder it would happen. However, we want to build a habitat. Thus we will have either a slowly counter-rotating shell or connections to other cylinders and free-fall industrial facilities in the same habit cluster. There is no reason to have storage and manufacturing on the habitat drum. These additional structure allow us to dampen down the oscillations before the flips can occur. This is assuming that we can't use dynamic or passive systems to stabilise the habitat.

Comment: @TheDyingOfLight I fully admit that is possible, and even likely. But that is more forces needed, and therefore more propulsion needed. Why would one choose a starting point that is inefficient, in a situation where you already have everything working against you? I merely wanted to point out that there are more efficient structures.

Comment: @AlexandraWilliams regarding "spinning the way you want them to" I'm aware of that and I think there is a question all about that. I'm not favoring the cylinder vs the torus but I think the effect I am talking about would be there too. I wouldn't mind knowing were there is more general info about these design differences

Comment: @GaultDrakkor sure. That works too.

Comment: @notovny   Yes I meant 19908 mph not m/s, my mistake. Also I did some other significant math wrong here and I still need to correct it. Regardless, the speed is less than 17000 mph at that altitude. I made other bigger mistakes like doubling this tidal effect. It be 7 lbs not 15. I'm also bugged that the effect seems to get worse the farther from Earth you go because the orbital speed gets less but the rotational speed stays the same. I need to look at that more closely before I edit the question.

Comment: @Daron I have no idea how to make pictures for questions. Is there an interface for drawing here? Why don't you say what that is rather than just criticize. Pictures are better sure but others get it.

Comment: @Join JBH  I want to edit my question but also format it better first. As a moderator maybe you can answer this: What software exists so people can show/illustrate math clearly and well formatted? I see it done a lot but I have no idea how it is done. The help center doesn't have that question answered and I can't even see how to submit that question to the help center - so I feel I have to ask individuals. Its kind of frustrating. Maybe there is package somewhere that is good at showing equations?

Answer (score 3):

“rotate around an axis that pointed away from Earth (or anywhere in a plane that is perpendicular to Earth).”

I’m not entirely clear what you mean by this. A rotating structure orbiting Earth with its axis pointing at Earths centre at one point in its orbit would have its axis parallel with Earth’s surface at a later point in its orbit as angular momentum is conserved.

Similarly a rotating object can’t orbit the Sun with its axis of rotation continually pointing at the Sun (at least not without using vast amounts of energy to continually change its angular momentum).

The orbital speed will have no effect upon the forces experienced inside the cylinder as it will be in free fall. Consider an astronaut in a spacecraft in a highly elliptical orbit around the Earth. The velocity of the spacecraft would vary greatly being relatively fast at closest approach to the Earth and relatively slow at furthest distance, but the astronaut would remain weightless throughout.

Comment: As far as the angular momentum issue. I imagined a structure just has to rotate about its own axis once every time it rotates around the earth - like the moon does. That doesn't work? I'd really like to know

Comment: I don't think the astronaut example is apt. See the other answer below. You are moving too slow to cancel true gravity when at point of closest or farthest from Earth in the cylinder. that effect adds to the simulated gravity. At least I think so. Its tidal. Same effect as with the moon - albeit with the moon the effect is trivial in what a person can feel. (If cylinder rotates the other way the farthest and closest points you will feel less gravity)

Comment: FYI: I think you got “rotate around an axis that pointed away from Earth (or anywhere in a plane that is perpendicular to Earth.” - correctly. I don't know how to draw a picture

Comment: But the Moon never has its axis of rotation pointed directly at the Earth. Its axis of rotation is never perpendicular to the Earth as you describe it.

Comment: I don't think the effect that you are talking about exists assuming the rotating structure is rigid. The part of the station rotation against the orbital direction would be counteracted by an opposite part of the station rotating the other way.

Comment: “I imagined a structure just has to rotate about its own axis once every time it rotates around the earth - like the moon does.”  And as the ISS does.

Comment: O'Neill's scheme has cylinders in counter-rotating tethered pairs, cancelling their angular momentum, so that the whole can precess to track the sun.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's reverse engineer a relevant parameter for tides, namely how big the structure is.  It rotates with outer edge at 173 m/s to provide, I assume, 9.8 m/s^2 gravity.  The apparent centrifugal acceleration (and real centripetal force) is 9.8 m/s^2 = w^2*r, where w is the angular velocity in radians.  More usefully, it's (173 m/s)^2/r, where r is still the radius.  So r = 3000 m.

Now the only difference in gravity people will *feel* will be the difference between the center point and 3 km in or out.  Alas we also don't know the orbital distance so we'll reverse engineer that - it's 19908 m/s to stay in orbit, versus Wikipedia's figure of 7900 m/s for staying in orbit at a hypothetical elevation of 0 km at Earth's equator.  Hmmm, there's no way you need that much velocity to orbit Earth.

Anyway, the tidal difference in gravity in a 6 km cylinder shouldn't be that extreme, in most situations.

Comment: He's not talking tidal difference.  Rather, that 173m/s is added to or subtracted from the orbital velocity around Earth.

Comment: I probably should show my math and I did make a mistake in using the wrong r for a height of 1000 miles and an even bigger mistake in doubling the effect. I didn't realize that the extra feeling of weight will happen when the person in cylinder is both at closest approach to earth and farthest. I thought that the feeling is lessened when at farthest point.  The tidal analogy is apt. I just haven't seen anyone discuss this problem if it were something orbiting close to Earth.